# Printing grep results to file and terminal

Tags: linux, bash, file, terminal, grep

I'm trying to display the grep results to the terminal as well as to a file. The solution I've come up with is to just run it twice, but this obviously will create efficiency issues.

```
grep -n "$SEARCH_TERM" "$i"
grep -n "$SEARCH_TERM" "$i" >> /file.txt
```

Is there a tag that will allow it to print to both using only one search?

Thanks

Comment: You could write it to the file first, then use cat to print to STDOUT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program you are looking for is "tee":

```
grep -n "$SEARCH_TERM" "$i" | tee -a /file.txt
```