# How to print each line that contains a certain string to a new txt file?

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to programming/scripting/everything, and I am trying to figure out how to go through each line of a .txt file I have, and write the lines that contain a specific string (like for example "United States of America") to new .txt file.

I know that the grep command prints out the line if it contains the string, but I am trying to figure out how I can write the line to a new file.

Are there certain commands that would help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Many of the good questions might already have good answers here. So please search before you ask.

Comment: actually it is the question that almost has been asked in both duplicates, but quite not the same :) Now I think we have all the questions and the answers. Done.

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. Just redirect grep results to a file

```
grep "United States of America" text.txt > results.txt
```

(use `>>` to append to `results.txt` instead of creating a new file)

Comment: Nice, but you might wish to search before answering if similar questions have been asked before..

Comment: The "possible duplicate" stated by tripleee isn't a duplicate. The real question is "how to redirect a command output to a file", but the OP did not even know that there's a generic way of doing it on Unix and even on Windows BTW. Maybe the OP was looking for an option of `grep`.

Comment: Either the question or the answer in the [\[ link \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203050/printing-grep-results-to-file-and-terminal) i suggested clearly addresses the problem mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -1):

If think what is you are looking for is `tee`. See the following example (hope it will answer the question).

`sh-4.3$ echo "1" > 1.txt

sh-4.3$ echo 2 >> 1.txt

sh-4.3$ echo 21 >> 1.txt

sh-4.3$ echo 22 >> 1.txt

sh-4.3$ grep 1 1.txt

1

21

sh-4.3$ grep 1 1.txt | tee 2

1

21

sh-4.3$ cat 2 
1
21`

Comment: There is no hint that the op is looking for `tee` and kindly format the code.